# Yii:how to add one language in humhub

Tags: php, yii

i use humhub

i wants add one language in that plugin

What code I should add that for I have more than language

Where the first language was chosen here. 
I do not know how that works.

```
  <?php  echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'language', Yii::app()->params['availableLanguages'], array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
```

Comment: You don't edit the code. You edit the language files in the /messages/ folders with translations for the default langs.

Comment: Or to add a language, a new folder I believe like /messages/MyLang/

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the configuration files, availableLanguages is defined in this file: 
https://github.com/humhub/humhub/blob/master/protected/config/_defaults.php

But better look inside all configuration files for availableLanguages param.

Also keep in mind this will only show another language in the dropdown. The translations should be created in a new messages directory for that language.

PS: I don't know Humhub, just Yii so this might not be the most correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add the new language to the 'configurable from admin panel' languages at: 
/protected/humhub/config/common.php

example:

```
'sq' => 'Shqip',
```

add the new language code to the  /protected/messages/config.php (languages array)

```
'languages' => [.....,'sq,....]
```

copy paste one of the existing languages and rename the folder to "sq"

that's it.